# df.style.format() having no effect on dataframe

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this in a Jupyter Notebook / learning Pandas.

df.shape = (18,7)
All are float64

```
def currency_format(x):
        return "${:,.0f}".format(x/1000000)
    dfResults.style.format(currency_format)
    dfResults
```

The formater never fires.  I tried subsets, no subsets  Not sure what I am missing.  dfResults just shows all values unformatted.

I can use pd.options to globally set the format, and it works.  Just trying to learn selective formatting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dfResults.style.format(currency_format)` has indeed no effect on your original `dfResults` simply because it returns a complete different object. Not to mention that it is a [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) (not a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)). Also, by switching to the former, you won't have access to the latter's [API](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) anymore. Another point, from what I understand through your code, you're running two expressions in the same Jupyter cell and since, by default, [only the last one is displayed](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity), you're seeing your original dataframe and thus, with it's default float formatting representation.

```
---------------------------------------- 
|def currency_format(x):                |
|    return "${:,.0f}".format(x/1000000)|
|                                       | 
|dfResults.style.format(currency_format)|
|dfResults                              | # << only this one is displayed
----------------------------------------
```

So if you're adjusting the format only for visual purposes, just remove `dfResults` in the end of the cell or store the styler in a separate variable and display it. Otherwise, if you still need to benefit from the DataFrame's API, setting a custom float format is your only [option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option) (*which you already did apparently*).

```
pd.set_option("display.float_format", lambda x: "${:,.0f}".format(x/1e6))
```

*You may also be interested by this Q/A : [Pandas : Set format for a single DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311271/pandas-set-format-for-single-dataframe).*

Comment: Thank you so very much.  I did try removing the last df and showing the styler, but my IDE/Notebook (Pycharm) shows an object reference.  Even print(styler) doesn't show it...  Regardless, I appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: Styler produces HTML. That HTML renders in a browser. In an IDE that is not capable of rendering HTML a Styler will be output as <object>